# FAILED: meson-internal__install

Tags: python, ninja, meson-build

I am installing kira throughout ninja and I get this error message

```
sudo ninja install
[0/1] Installing files.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 146, in run
return options.run_func(options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 811, in run
installer.do_install(datafilename)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 564, in do_install
d = self.check_installdata(pickle.load(ifile))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'OptionString' on <module       'mesonbuild.interpreter.primitives.string' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/primitives/string.py'>

ERROR: Unhandled python exception

This is a Meson bug and should be reported!
FAILED: meson-internal__install 
/home/dgagg/.local/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is the procedure I followed

To compile and install `Kira`, run

::

```
 meson --prefix=/install/path builddir
 cd builddir
 ninja
 ninja install
```

I run ninja and compiled, then it gave the aforementioned error.